# Laravel 5.1 Ajax call to controller's method error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm doing an ajax call to controller's method, I made some attempts, but don't know where is the problem.

First try:

```
public function show(Request $request, $from, $to)
{
    //return $request;
    $envData = EnviromentalData::whereBetween('data_recorded', array($from, $to))->get();
    return TransformService::transform($envData);
}
```

Output: `{"from":["The from field is required."],"to":["The to field is required."]}", responseJSON: Object, status: 422, statusText: "Unprocessable Entity"`

And, ofc,those fields 'from' and 'to' have values.

Second try:

```
public function show(Request $request) {
   return $request; 
}
```

Output: undefined

So the question is what is the problem? Also, I added two additional files of routes.php and script.js, I hope it will help.

```
routes.php
----------
Route::get('dashboard', 'DashboardController@dashboard');
Route::get('dashboard/from/{from}/to/{to}', 'DashboardController@show');

scripts.js
----------
// Ajax call to update the dashboard
function loadChart() {
    $.getJSON(window.location.href + '/from/' + fromDate + '/to/' + toDate)
}
```

Comment: Why are you returning a request? Shouldn't it be a response instead?

Comment: I made it for testing purposes, as u can see it's 'undefined' and this is very strange for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found my problem and it was in two places:

1) `return json_encode($request);`

2) fixed `scripts.js` file, added some logic for `.done()` method and `.fail()` and all started working!

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to add `Request $request`

Try this

```
routes.php
----------
Route::get('dashboard/from/{from}/to/{to}', 'DashboardController@show');


controller.php
--------------
public function show($from, $to) {
   return Response::json($request) ;
}
```

If you get data from ajax means you have return data as json.

Comment: Isn't that clearly undefined error or don't get what you all are trying to accomplish here? :)

Comment: I think I found a problem, when I was returning $request I should return json_encode($request);